# Change the cell values , using Pandas (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I need some help with pandas dataframe.
Look the image:
[image]

As you can see, I have some rows where the value are equal, like for example **"Type address"** or **"Public Place"**.

But I Want to transforme this excel rows in columns.

Using the follow code :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

df = pd.read_excel('myfile.xlsx')

tester = df.values.tolist()
keys = list(zip(*tester))[0]
seen = set()
seen_add = seen.add
keysu= [x for x in keys if not (x in seen or seen_add(x))]
values = list(zip(*tester))[1]

a = np.array(values).reshape(int(len(values)/len(keysu)),len(keysu))
list1 = [keysu]
for i in a:
    list1.append(list(i))
df = pd.DataFrame(list1)
df.to_excel('output.xlsx',index=False,header=False)
```

Owin to the fact that, equal values aren´t working as well as I want.

What I want:

change the equals **"Type address"**, for example into **"Type address 1"**, **"Type address 2 "**. **"Type address 3"**, depends on the repetition.

But how can I do that? Somebody can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate over the column and replace them as needed.  Something like this maybe:

```
counter = 1
result = []
for i in df.iloc[:, 0]:
    if i == "Type address":
        result.append(f"{i} {counter}")
    else:
        result.append(i)
    counter += 1

df.iloc[:, 0] = result
```

Above I use f-strings (Python 3.6 or above), if you are on an older version of python, you can replace it with `"{i} {counter}".format(i, counter)`.

Comment: Tks!  It is perfect!   `def changename(oldname):
    counter = 1
    result = []
    newval = 1
    for y in df.iloc[:, 0]:
        if (y == oldname):
            if (newval > 3):
                newval = 1
            result.append(f"{y} {newval}")
            newval = newval + 1 
        else:
            result.append(y)
        counter += 1
    df.iloc[:, 0] = result`

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you want to transpose the shown table and rename the column names, such that duplicate names have a incrementing number appended.

Here is how I would go about this:

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'\\s90104\Users\U118694\userdata\test.xlsx', index_col=0)

# Transpose DataFrame as desired
df = df.transpose()

# Detect duplicate column names first
duplicates = []
all_col = set(df.columns)
for i in all_col:
    if list(df.columns).count(i) > 1:
        duplicates.append(i)

# Generate new column names
col_names = []
for col in df.columns:
    if col in duplicates:
        n = 1
        col_n = "{} {:d}".format(col, n)
        while col_n in col_names:
            n +=  1
            col_n = "{} {:d}".format(col, n)
        col_names.append(col_n)
    else:
        col_names.append(col)

# Finally assign new column names
df.columns = col_names
```